# Passing exceptions through class to main window

Tags: c#, visual-studio

So i am making a program for school, the section i am working on currently i have an if statement set up and when the if is false it will throw and exception, I have a catch set up in the main window but the exception is never caught just thrown, which stops the program. I understand i need the catch in the main window because that is the only location i can have a messagebox.show. But how do i pass the exception throughout multiple classes?

Comment: Please choose one programming language. C and C# are two very different ones.

Comment: Normally the exception should "bubble up" until it is caught in your main window (if the method that throws that exception was called inside the above `try` block). To further help you, you should add some code to your question so we can see what you really did.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException 
        += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(ErrorHandler.HandleException);
```